# Attribute name, created from an expression in Twig

Tags: php, twig

In php template I have an object `$obj`, which has some attributes like `$obj->attr_1, $obj->attr_2` etc.
How can I call them from Twig template in the for loop?

I tried like this:

```
{% for i in 1..3 %}
  {% set new_attr = 'attr_' ~ i %}
  {{obj.new_attr}}
{% endfor %}
```

or like this

```
{% for i in 1..3 %}
  {% set new_attr = 'attr_' ~ i %}
  {{obj[new_attr]}}
{% endfor %}
```

but it does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using [attribute](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/functions/attribute.html) function.

Answer (score 0):

Neither approach will work.  In the first, new_attr is a string value, so I *believe* that obj.new_attr will attempt string concatenation.  The second approach won't work because it treats obj as an array, which is a different thing to an object.

What you're asking for is reflection - the ability to ask an object for information about itself, such as its methods.  PHP has rudimentary support for reflection as documented here http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.reflection.php (see the getMethods entry) but it requires installation of an extension.

As an alternative, why not have a single method on your object called get, which takes a number and then calls the appropriate method, such as

```
public function get($attr)
{
   if ($attr == 1) return $this->attr_1();
   // etc...
}
```